# R - Parameter estimates for non central chi squared distribution

Tags: r, estimation, chi-squared-distribution, non-central

I have a vector that has a non-central chi-squared distribution. How do I estimate its distributional parameters i.e. degrees of freedom $d$ and non-centrality parameter $\lambda$?

Comment: I would consult Kubokawa, Robert, Saleh, _Estimation of Noncentrality Parameters_, 1993.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done accurately according to what the researhes achieved, the best numerical unbiased estimator is (2.8) in the first paper:

[Unbiased Estimation in the Non-central Chi-Square Distribution](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X00918980)

[An Approximation of the Non-central Chi-Square Distribution](http://www.utstat.toronto.edu/dfraser/documents/192.pdf)

[Estimation of the Non-Centrality Parameter of a Chi-Square Distribution](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a083527.pdf)

I don't think there is an R-package estimating this noncentral parameter, altough I know that `fpow` can estimate noncentral parameters of F-distributions.